# Loading SCNScene from URL

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am trying to load a SCNScene from a URL. I see that there is an initializers of SCNScene which takes in a URL but it always throws exception when used.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://mywebsite.com/publicfolder/bunny.dae")!
        let scene = try! SCNScene(url: url, options: nil)
```

The error is not very descriptive it just says:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

I am thinking that the URL does not mean http web URL but it might meant a URL in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC SceneKit supports only local (`file:`) URLs. Also, SceneKit in iOS can’t natively read “raw” DAE format — only DAE files that you put in your app bundle via Xcode (which preprocesses them into an iOS-optimized format but keeps the “.dae” extension).

On top of all that, you’re ignoring errors raised by your method call there: `try!` causes your app to crash instead of letting you inspect/handle the error.

Nonetheless, I’m pretty sure `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` isn’t the kind of crash you ought to be getting in that case. I’d recommend [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) about the lack of correct error message.